# What case of inheritance will be correct, rectangle from Square or conversely?

Tags: oop, inheritance, design-patterns

What case of inheritance will be correct? 
When we inherit rectangle from square or square from rectangle or we shouldn't do inherit in this case?

Comment: What about inheriting both of them from Class *Shape*?

Comment: As you probably know, square **is** always a rectangle, but rectangle does not have to be a square.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/584732/414076 Listen to Uncle Bob. Or at least someone summarizing Uncle Bob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mathematically, a square is a rectangle.

but oo-wise, a square is *not* a rectangle because it will break the [liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

see also the [circle ellipse problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem).

Answer (score -1):

Yes As per "Muhahhad Faizan Uddin" said square is always a rectangle, but vice versa is not always true.
But if can see square if more of specific shape and rectangle is generalized term.
So In my experience Square should Inherit rectangle class.